# Understanding Module Scope in Nested React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While refactoring some code at work, I ran into a circular dependency with nested React components. The feature was basically "Use a switch to dynamically render components nested in other components, including themselves".

I solved the problem by creating a component "registry" with two methods, `registerBlock` and an HOC `BlockRegistry`.

#### src/BlocksNode.js

```
// src/BlocksNode.js - accepts and renders a block passed from the API

import BlockRegistry, { registerBlock } from './BlockRegister'
import ComponentOne from './ComponentOne'
import ComponentTwo from './ComponentTwo'

// accepts a name and a component
registerBlock('componentOne', ComponentOne)
registerBlock('componentTwo', ComponentTwo)

// reads a block from the API and uses the type passed from props
const BlocksNode = (props) => {
const { type, blocks } = props
return <BlockRegistry type={type} blocks={blocks} />
}
export default BlocksNode
```

#### src/BlockRegister.js

```
const components = {}

export function registerBlock(name, Component) {
  components[name] = Component
}

const BlockRegistry = (props) => {
  const { type, ...rest } = props
  const Component = components[type]
  return <Component {...rest} />
}

export default BlockRegistry
```

#### src/ComponentOne.js

```
import BlockRegistry from './BlockRegister'

function ComponentOne(props) {
  const { blocks } = props
  return (
    <div>
      {blocks.map((block) => {
        const { type, blocks } = block
        return <BlockRegistry type={type} blocks={blocks} />
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ComponentOne
```

`ComponentOne.js` can pass any number of other blocks, including `ComponentTwo.js` or itself. I've simplified some of the logic, but the gist is there.

This solution works great. But I don't understand how it's able to function. Logically I'd expect the nested component's scope to *not* include the top-level, registered components. How is scope being handled so that nested components are working without new, nested calls to `registerBlock()`?

For instance, how does `<BlockRegistry />` in `ComponentOne.js` find a match for `block.type === 'componentTwo'`? I'd expect to need to re-register it, ie. by doing `registerBlock('componentTwo', ComponentTwo)` inside `ComponentOne.js`. The fact that it works without the call seems strange.